# How can I speed up a zfs resilver on a 24x 16TB drive draid2 array: "117T total... 47 days 02:31:23 to go"

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, software-raid, lsi, seagate

(My apologies for the multiple edits to clarify formatting)

As above. The drives show no SMART errors.

Is there a way to check for HBA <--> drive communication errors?

This is running under Ubuntu 22.04 on a Supermicro platform with an AMD 64-core Threadripper Pro CPU, 256GB ECC RAM, LSI HBAs, and 24 16TB Seagate X18 drives. Power is filtered via an OneAC isolation transformer.

Here's the `zpool status` output:

```
  pool: lake_24x16TB  
 state: ONLINE  
status: One or more devices is currently being resilvered.  The pool will  
    continue to function, possibly in a degraded state.  
action: Wait for the resilver to complete.  
  scan: resilver in progress since Thu Sep  7 19:06:13 2023  
    4.21T scanned at 135M/s, 959G issued at 30.0M/s, 117T total  
    177G resilvered, 0.80% done, 46 days 22:15:51 to go  
config:  
  
NAME                                     STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM  
lake_24x16TB                             ONLINE       0     0     0  
  draid2:21d:24c:1s-0                    ONLINE       0     0     0  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM001G-2KK103_ZL______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    spare-20                             ONLINE       0     0     0  
      ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______  ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
      draid2-0-0                         ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
    ata-ST16000NM000J-2TW103_ZR______    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)  
spares  
  draid2-0-0                             INUSE     currently in use  

errors: No known data errors
```

And here is the first pass of the `iostat -x -k 1` output:

```
Linux 6.2.0-32-generic (Kaala)  09/09/2023  _x86_64_    (128 CPU)    
  
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle  
           0.11    0.00    3.10   16.29    0.00   80.49  
  
Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz     f/s f_await  aqu-sz  %util  
loop0            0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     1.21    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00  
loop1            0.01      0.03     0.00   0.00    0.02     2.90    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00  
loop10           0.04      0.12     0.00   0.00    0.02     2.91    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00  
loop11           0.05      0.53     0.00   0.00    0.06    11.01    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00  
loop12           0.01      0.03     0.00   0.00    0.02     2.59    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00  
loop13           0.00      0.01     0.00   0.00    0.10     4.80    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00  
loop14           0.00      0.01     0.00   0.00    0.18     7.22    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00  
loop15           0.02      0.67     0.00   0.00    0.25    36.36    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00  
loop16           0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.05     2.70    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00  
loop17           0.00      0.01     0.00   0.00    0.12     9.81    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00  
loop18           0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     1.27    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00  
loop2            0.01      0.03     0.00   0.00    0.02     2.88    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00  
loop3            0.01      0.06     0.00   0.00    0.03     4.35    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00  
loop4            0.02      0.17     0.00   0.00    0.15     8.17    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00  
loop5            0.00      0.03     0.00   0.00    0.10    16.14    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00  
loop6            0.00      0.03     0.00   0.00    0.14    15.12    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00  
loop7            0.02      0.07     0.00   0.00    0.02     3.91    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00  
loop8            0.02      0.07     0.00   0.00    0.02     3.89    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00  
loop9            0.02      0.08     0.00   0.00    0.03     3.78    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00  
nvme0n1          1.95     61.41     0.53  21.39    0.16    31.42    3.71     55.30     3.15  45.95    1.64    14.91    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.24    0.90    0.01   0.34  
sda            657.15  17662.73     0.00   0.00    2.46    26.88  674.99   7473.83    15.98   2.31    0.59    11.07    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   61.75    2.02  80.00  
sdb            654.70  17626.14     0.00   0.00    2.47    26.92  673.86   7469.65    16.29   2.36    0.59    11.08    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   60.57    2.02  80.01  
sdc            657.38  17589.65     0.00   0.00    2.64    26.76  671.59   7476.97    15.74   2.29    0.60    11.13    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   66.51    2.15  80.11  
sdd            659.12  17616.74     0.00   0.00    2.50    26.73  670.35   7474.24    15.95   2.32    0.60    11.15    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   63.60    2.06  79.98  
sde            651.63  17480.21     0.00   0.00    2.34    26.83  554.62   7472.05    16.00   2.80    0.94    13.47    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   65.38    2.06  79.99  
sdf            625.72  16634.25     0.00   0.00    1.83    26.58  671.25   7719.82    15.92   2.32    0.61    11.50    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   63.77    1.57  77.70  
sdg            653.95  17600.39     0.00   0.00    2.61    26.91  666.46   7468.19    15.91   2.33    0.61    11.21    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   64.79    2.13  80.09  
sdh            655.76  17574.57     0.00   0.00    2.69    26.80  670.95   7467.93    15.91   2.32    0.60    11.13    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   67.54    2.18  80.10  
sdi            655.44  17568.31     0.00   0.00    2.45    26.80  671.10   7471.13    15.91   2.32    0.60    11.13    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   62.33    2.02  79.93  
sdj            647.18  17203.93     0.00   0.00    2.35    26.58  677.54   7540.63    15.81   2.28    0.58    11.13    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   63.77    1.93  79.73  
sdk            655.07  17638.54     0.00   0.00    2.60    26.93  670.18   7472.87    15.75   2.30    0.60    11.15    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   63.95    2.11  80.03  
sdl            656.55  17653.16     0.00   0.00    2.37    26.89  677.64   7473.03    16.05   2.31    0.58    11.03    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   62.99    1.96  79.93  
sdm            654.57  17561.50     0.00   0.00    2.56    26.83  670.79   7476.85    15.76   2.30    0.60    11.15    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   63.98    2.09  80.16  
sdn            654.64  17541.64     0.00   0.00    2.38    26.80  673.14   7472.02    15.90   2.31    0.59    11.10    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   61.28    1.97  79.85  
sdo            673.34  17649.85     0.00   0.00    2.27    26.21  677.04   7472.21    16.03   2.31    0.58    11.04    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   62.22    1.93  79.98  
sdp            650.65  17476.46     0.00   0.00    2.26    26.86  678.38   7473.77    16.17   2.33    0.58    11.02    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   60.67    1.87  79.80  
sdq            650.07  17629.95     0.00   0.00    2.31    27.12  677.22   7475.71    16.05   2.32    0.59    11.04    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   62.94    1.91  79.70  
sdr            655.26  17605.45     0.00   0.00    2.52    26.87  672.01   7477.66    15.98   2.32    0.60    11.13    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   63.34    2.06  79.98  
sds            652.57  17599.76     0.00   0.00    6.64    26.97  455.75   8149.03    11.96   2.56    2.17    17.88    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18  116.58    5.34  86.73  
sdt            651.14  17549.92     0.00   0.00    2.58    26.95  671.98   7475.30    15.98   2.32    0.60    11.12    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   64.62    2.09  79.96  
sdu            678.75  17761.68     0.00   0.00    2.20    26.17  679.47   7472.43    15.94   2.29    0.58    11.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   60.03    1.90  80.07  
sdv            653.08  17555.64     0.00   0.00    2.35    26.88  673.80   7476.29    15.94   2.31    0.59    11.10    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   62.13    1.94  79.75  
sdw            655.08  17615.29     0.00   0.00    2.42    26.89  673.54   7470.69    16.05   2.33    0.59    11.09    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   63.18    1.99  79.92  
sdx            652.01  17484.18     0.00   0.00    2.41    26.82  676.29   7475.99    15.84   2.29    0.59    11.05    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   61.02    1.98  79.80
```

Comment: Please show the output of `zpool status` and `iostat -x -k 1`

Comment: hm im unsure but i remember that a log device could speed it up and does a backup exists in case of an issue?

Comment: Yes, I have a backup on a separate server. No log device though. Ubuntu and the swap space is on the solid state drive, with dual boot to win10x64 available for access to tools not available on Ubuntu.

Comment: Far from being a zfs expert, but I have had pools go into degraded mode because they lost connection to one side of the mirror for a short while. After getting the lost disk back the resilver started and estimated time was several days. It was over within a day though. So estimate can vary a lot. Best is to do a rough estimate in your head about how much data was missed on the missing devices. If it ain't in the order of TB I wouldn't worry about this estimate.

Comment: Is this better now?

Answer (score 1):

Scrub is in the metadata scanning phase, which mainly involves small reads with low transfer rate. Data resilver is going to be slow until metadata scanning finishes. Rather than messing with ZFS module parameters and/or other settings, simply be patient: your resilver speed is going to accelerate in the near future.